# "I did well" vs. "I did good"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, adjectives, adverbs

> I did well.
>
> I did good.

Which one is a correct sentence?
Please explain it with reasons.
Can you please define them?

Comment: Sander's answer describes the standard use of *I did good*.  Cookie Monster's answer describes the non-standard use of *I did good*, and so does Khan's.  Unfortunately, we don't have a single answer covering both uses, so make sure you read all the answers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did well.

I did good.

More often than not, it's well, not good, that you use as an adverb.  The word good is mainly an adjective, but it's also used as an adverb in informal AE.  So both the sentences are OK.

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences can be correct, but they have a different meaning.

In the first sentence, *well* is an adverb that modifies *did*. *Well* is the adverbial form of *good*, and in this case it means that what the speaker did, he did in a good way, with good results. When writing sentences like this, ensure that you know which word is being modified. If it modifies a noun, an adjective is used while an adverb is used to modify verbs or adjectives:

> A *good* **man**.

The word *good* modifies the noun *man* which requires it to be in its adjective form. In your sentence it modifies the verb and is in the adverbial form:

> I **did** *well*.

Now, this might make you think that your second sentence is wrong, but it is not. It does, however, have a different meaning than the first sentence. In that second sentence, *good* is used as a **noun**. It cannot be used as an adjective because there is no noun next to it to be modified nor is there a copular verb which could link it to the subject. The phrase *do good* is used in the meaning of *be benificial, aid*. It is often used with a direct object, the person or object that benefits or receives the  aid. Here's an example with the phrase *to do someone good*:

> - A: I'm feeling sick.
> - B: Drink some tea, it will **do** *you* **good**.

You can see how this meaning is very different from your first sentence. You can *do well* on an exam, but you can't *do good* on it. You can, however, do good by helping someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Only the following version is considered grammatically correct:

> I did well on the test.

The reason being is that *well* is an adverb modifying the verb *did*. You use adverbs to make your verbs sound more colorful. That's their primary function.

However, many Americans do say:

> I did pretty good on the test.

which is, of course, grammatically incorrect because *good* is an adjective. Adjectives are only used to modify nouns. So, what we have here is called a colloquialism—something that's accepted in spoken language because of its widespread use despite the fact that it's grammatically wrong. I have an American teacher who himself many times uses *good* instead of the proper form *well* which only goes to show how extremely common it has become to say *good* instead of *well* in daily English. But, I bet ya, when he has to write something like a business letter or simply send a notification message to his students, he's definitely going to use the proper form *well*.

So, my recommendations:

- when you speak, always use *well* unless you feel comfortable enough with the language
- accept that you are going to hear Americans say *I did good* a lot
- on an English test, always use *well*. If you don't, you're going to lose points

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand it is to realize you have contracted both sentences.  In other words you left out words unnecessary for the reader to understand what you are saying.

In the first sentence, the uncontracted form would be

> I did the job very well.

describing how you did it.

In the second sentence it would be

> I did a good job

describing what you or what you did.